# Is there a way to make my discord bot disconnect from the voice channel after finishing playing a song?

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio, pafy

I was wondering if there was a way to make my discord bot leave the voice channel after playing the audio of a youtube video. I tried using `sleep(duration of the video)`, but for getting and downloading the video to play, I used `pafy`, which gives me the duration of the video, but in the 00:00:00 format, which counts as a string, not an interger. I changed the code to diconnect at the `after=lamda e: await vc.disconnect`, but it gives me an error saying `'await' outside async function`. My code for playing the music is below:

```
channel = message.author.voice.channel
vc = await channel.connect()
url = contents
url = url.strip("play ")
video = pafy.new(url)
await message.channel.send("Now playing **%s**" % video.title)

audio = video.getbestaudio()
audio.download()
duration = video.duration
player = vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('%s.webm' % video.title), after=lambda e: await vc.disconnect)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to disconnect after the song completes (removing the `after=`).

Add after `vc.play()`

```py
    while vc.is_playing():
        await sleep(1)
    await vc.disconnect()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me an error, saying that I cannot use await on sleep. Even when I took await away, it still could not work.

Comment: You need to import - `from asyncio import sleep`

Comment: Oh, I did `from time import sleep`.

Comment: I still got `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited` and lots of other stuff after that.

Comment: did you put the await back and is properly indented?

Answer (score 1):

Code I use in my bot:

```
stop_event = asyncio.Event()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
def after(error):
    if error:
        logging.error(error)
    def clear():
        stop_event.set()
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(clear)

audio = PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(file_path), 1)
client.play(audio, after=after)

await stop_event.wait()
await client.disconnect()
```

Comment: Previously I was using kind of solution from accepted answer, but came up with a cleaner way above

Answer (score 0):

In this case the `vc.disconnect()` is a coroutine which must be awaited.
The `after` function of the discord player can't await async functions like this. Instead use something like this:

```
def my_after(error):
coro = vc.disconnect()
fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, client.loop)
try:
    fut.result()
except:
    # an error happened sending the message
    pass
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url), after=my_after)
```

[You can also read about it here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-pass-a-coroutine-to-the-player-s-after-function)